# Products in Magento stores homepage won't line up horizontally in grid

Tags: magento

I am creating a Magento store and would like to have three products lined up across the home page horizontally with product name and 'add to cart' links directly below each product image. The problem I am currently having with this is that each new product after the first one (e.g., products 2 and 3) seem to get pushed down about 10px from the last product. I have the catalog configured to only display products in a 'grid' and have set a limit to display only 3 products in the grid.

You can view the store front @ http://deadlydash.com/shop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the pre opening and closing tags with the code class, then remove the top:-100px; from products-grid class

Comment: I actually have another odd 'bug' with the product images. Only half the image (which at the moment is a placeholder) is clickable.

http://deadlydash.com/shop/

Comment: The following div is overlayed on top of your image link. 

.products-grid .actions

if you add a clear:both; to this class it should clear it up then you will just have to reposition with the top and right to realign.

Please mark the answer above as correct if you feel it was the right answer. Thanks

Comment: @JonDay That comment can be improved... Only to explain a bit better for newbies...